# Append data in text file does not work in android application

Tags: java, android, file, gps, text-files

I'm using the following code for append new position data obtained by GPS, each time position change.

```
if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
    if (myFile.exists()) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude()+", "+nodeCounter+"\n");
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            nodeCounter++;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    } else {
        try {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}else
{
    Log.i("logGPSData","Error");
}
```

The problem is that the append does not work, since each time a new row is inserted, the previous row is overwritten, so my file contains always one line, even if I collect many gps data.

Comment: Change the lines to: FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile,true);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut,true);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument means if text should be appended to the existing file, change the following lines in your code:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
```

to:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile,true);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut,true);
```

[From the Docs:](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

```
public FileOutputStream(String name,boolean append)
                 throws FileNotFoundException
```

Creates a file output stream to write to the file with the specified name. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning. A new FileDescriptor object is created to represent this file connection.
First, if there is a security manager, its checkWrite method is called with name as its argument.

If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.

#### Parameters:

1) name - the system-dependent file name

2) append - if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning

#### Throws:

1)FileNotFoundException - if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason.

2)SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkWrite method denies write access to the file.

#### Since:

JDK1.1